# Integrable function on positive axis.

Tags: singular-integrals

Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and that $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} \,dx  < \infty.$$ Does it follow that $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(x)^2}{x} \,dx < \infty     ?$$

Comment: Do you have more information about the function? Maybe it's value range....

Comment: You may assume that you have $e^{-x}$ for $x\to \infty$ and at most a power singularity at zero.

Comment: It’s a real valued function !!

Comment: I asked that because that's not true unless we have a specified range of that function!!

Comment: What if $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$?  The answer given (@Riemann) would not apply.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \,dx  =\frac{\pi}{2},$$
but $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x} \,dx  $ is divergent, because
$$\frac{\sin^2 x}{x}=\frac{1-cos 2x}{2x}.$$